# Wordpress: Refreshing Permalinks with Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress

My current hierarchy is as follows:

- Custom Post Type: Projects (projects.php)
- single-projects.php

I've checked out this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202859/custom-post-type-pages-are-not-found, but flush_rewrite_rules( false ); doesn't seem to work. I've also tried manually saving on the permalinks page, but it was either the projects.php being able to appear, or single-projects.php appearing, but not both.

Code in functions.php from https://getflywheel.com/layout/how-to-create-a-portfolio-for-your-wordpress-site/:

```
    //Creating Custom Post types for Projects
function setup_projects_cpt(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Project'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
        'new_item' => __('New Project'),
        'all_items' => __('All Projects'),
        'view_item' => __('View Project'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
        'not_found' => __('No Projects Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Projects found in the trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Projects'
        );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'My Projects',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array(''),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite', //Find the appropriate dashicon here: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/
        );
    register_post_type('projects', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'setup_projects_cpt');

//The following snippet is used to enable categories for the projects CPT. 
function projects_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'project_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (no spaces and all lowercase. no caps). 
        'projects',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Project Categories',  //Label Displayed in the Admin when creating a new project
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'projects', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'projects_taxonomy');

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'projects' ) ); // adds thumbnail support for the Projects CPT
```

Comment: have you save your permalinks from admin side.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too @dineshkashera. Somehow only either projects.php or single-projects.php will appear -_-

Comment: Please paste your code for register custom post type, it will help to find the issue .

Comment: ok, just included. @dineshkashera

Comment: you have set the same slug for rewrite , it will create problem, please use different rewrite name for post and taxonomy.

Comment: If you mean just changing the parts with array('slug' => 'projects'), it still doesn't seem to work. Used projects for post and project for taxonomy... @dineshkashera

Comment: What is projects.php? Shouldn't it be archive-projects.php?

Comment: Save the permalinks and check. It will work

Answer (score 0):

[You registered projects custom post.

- You can find "Settings > Permalinks" in the dashboard
- Scroll down and select **Custom Structure** then click **Save Changes**
- Rewrite rules and permalinks are flushed.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45waR.png)

Comment: Flushed rewrite rules and permalinks using this method; problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same rewrite slug for both projects custom post type and project categories that's why it may cause the issue

Try to change anyone you might be get resolved it

Note: flush rewrite rule after change

Comment: Even removing project categories entirely, the problem still exists.